# Rails mapping data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Rails application with a database structured like this: [image: database structure]

The user selects some expertises and it's all saved as expected, same for the profiles, the profiles select some expertises and all is saved as expected. I can find profiles associated with expertise.

user model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :expertises
```

Expertise model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Now, let's say a user selects some expertises and I want to show all the profiles with the same expertises? Any ideas on how to do this?

Could this be done in the controller or would I need to create another join table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `has_many :matching_profiles, :through => :expertises, class_name => "Profile", :source => :profiles`

then you can do `@user.matching_profiles` to find all of the profiles that have matching expertise's

You would also have to have

`has_many :profiles, :through => :expertise_profiles, :source => :profile` in the Expertise class

and `has_many :expertises, :through => :user_expertises, :source => :expertise` in the User class

Comment: If you want to display the profiles that match each expertise a user has, then you would want this in a controller

`@expertises = @user.expertises.includes(:profiles)`

then in your views loop through @expertises

`<% @expertises.each do |expertise| %>
  <%= expertise.name %>
  <%= expertise.profiles.map(&:name).join(", ") %>
%< end %>

assuming a name column on each model

Comment: I'm getting an error `Could not find the association :expertises_recruiter in model Recruiter`

Comment: also where would I put this `@user.matching_profiles` this could be why I'm getting an error

Comment: I'm getting an error `Could not find the association :expertises_user in model User`

Comment: The code I suggested works with has_may :through as opposed to has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: So you would need to create the join tables themselves - expertise_profiles and expertise_users in a migration.